# EventPublisher возникает java.util.ConcurrentModificationException при доступе к ArrayList

Tags: java, многопоточность, arraylist, итераторы

Есть класс:

```
@Component
public class EventPublisherImpl implements EventPublisher {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private List<EventListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void addListener(EventListener toAdd) {
        listeners.add(toAdd);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeListener(EventListener toRemove) {
        listeners.remove(toRemove);
    }

    public void publicEvent(AmiObject amiObject) {
        if (listeners != null && !listeners.isEmpty()) {
            Iterator<EventListener> iterator = listeners.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext())
                synchronized (iterator) {
                    EventListener eventListener = iterator.next();
                    if (eventListener != null) {
                        eventListener.publicEvent(amiObject);
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

EventListener'ы добавляются в него из разных нитей.

Так вот при запуске возникает ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1042)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:996)
    at ...EventPublisherImpl.publicEvent(EventPublisherImpl.java:34)
    at ...AmiObjectParserImpl.parseStr(AmiObjectParserImpl.java:45)
    at ...ConnectorImpl.listenSocket(ConnectorImpl.java:214)
    at ...ConnectorImpl.run(ConnectorImpl.java:92)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

и указывает на строчку

```
EventListener eventListener = iterator.next();
```

Comment: Не можно изменять коллекцию во время итерации по ней. Итератор становиться не валидным, после любых изменений листа во время итерации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итератор [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) не поддерживает параллельное изменение списка кроме изменений через методы самого итератора. При обнаружении параллельного изменения выбрасывается `ConcurrentModificationException` об этом написано в документации:

> The iterators returned by this class's `iterator` and `listIterator` methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

К тому же сам [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) не является потокобезопасным, это может привести к другим ошибкам и расхождениям в данных. То, что список несинхронизирован и что нужно делать для безопасной работы из нескольких потоков тоже написано в документации:

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized.** If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array; merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification.) This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the list. If no such object exists, the list should be "wrapped" using the [`Collections.synchronizedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-) method. This is best done at creation time, to prevent accidental unsynchronized access to the list:
>
> `List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));`

Чтобы исправить код нужно поступить согласно рекомендациям.

1. Синхронизировать список через [`Collections.synchronizedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-):

```
private List<EventListener> listeners = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<EventListener>());
```

2. Перед чтением списка синхронизироваться по нему:

```
synchronized(listeners) {
    for(EventListener l : listeners) {
        l.publicEvent(amiObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, так и поступил. Ошибка ушла.

Comment: @VitalyM. Пожалуйста! Рад что помогло.

Answer (score 2):

Захват такого монитора

```
synchronized (iterator) {...}
```

не имеет смысла, т.к. `listeners.iterator();` возвращает каждому зашедшему потоку новый объект - итератор, пруф из класса `ArrayList`

> ```
> /**
>  * Returns an iterator over the elements in this list in proper sequence.
>  *
>  * <p>The returned iterator is <a href="#fail-fast"><i>fail-fast</i></a>.
>  *
>  * @return an iterator over the elements in this list in proper sequence
>  */
> public Iterator<E> iterator() {
>     return new Itr();
> }
> ```

синхронизируйтесь на пример на самой коллекции

```
synchronized (listeners)  {...}
```

Comment: Такой вариант я пробовал изначально... возможно я ошибся, но по моему так тоже выскакивала эта ошибка...

Comment: Сделал так - private final static Object monitor = new Object();

Comment: ну и по этому объекту уже синхронизирую

Comment: Мне кажется, что `ConcurrentModificationException` никак не связан с синхронизацией. имхо..

Comment: эту же ошибку я получал и при `for(EventListener eventListener : listeners)`, поэтому я и добавил синхронизацию

Comment: @VitalyM. если у вас нету других вариантов кроме как изменять эту коллекцию во время итерации, сделайте ее копию в этой же функции и  изменяйте копию коллекции, а потом подмените ее ссылку на `listeners`. но это очень грубый `work around`.